# Unable to send e-mail via sendmail, because User is unknown

Tags: 7, emails

```
*hostname.domain.com is substituted throughout for my actual subdomain*
```

### My Setup

I have **Drupal 7.14** on an **OpenVZ VPS** running **Ubuntu 11.10** (also tested with 10.04).  Ubuntu has installed the repository versions of Apache2/php5/mysql, (**not the LAMP metapackage**) with php5.ini configured to dump all error messages to `syslog`.

### My Problem

Consistently, when the site is to send an email to any address, it returns:

> Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

And the Drupal Error in 'Recent log messages' readds:

> Error sending e-mail (from noreply@hostname.domain.com to noreply@hostname.domain.com).

This Error shows in the Drupal logs no matter what address the email is being sent to.

*The email does actually end up sending after a short delay.*  Usually 1 second, but also 6 or more seconds.

### Contents of Syslog

```
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sendmail[1648]: q8LDMYe9001648: Authentication-Warning: hostname.domain.com: www-data set sender to noreply@hostname.domain.com using -f
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sendmail[1648]: q8LDMYe9001648: from=noreply@hostname.domain.com, size=649, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201209211322.q8LDMYe9001648@hostname.domain.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sm-mta[1649]: q8LDMYxB001649: from=<noreply@hostname.domain.com>, size=1023, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201209211322.q8LDMYe9001648@hostname.domain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sendmail[1648]: q8LDMYe9001648: to=newuser@fakedomain.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30649, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (q8LDMYxB001649 Message accepted for delivery)
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sendmail[1653]: q8LDMYgo001653: Authentication-Warning: hostname.domain.com: www-data set sender to noreply@hostname.domain.com using -f
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sendmail[1653]: q8LDMYgo001653: from=noreply@hostname.domain.com, size=465, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201209211322.q8LDMYgo001653@hostname.domain.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sm-mta[1654]: q8LDMY0G001654: <noreply@hostname.domain.com>... User unknown
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sendmail[1653]: q8LDMYgo001653: to=noreply@hostname.domain.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30465, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sm-mta[1654]: q8LDMY0G001654: from=<noreply@hostname.domain.com>, size=465, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sendmail[1653]: q8LDMYgo001653: q8LDMYgp001653: DSN: User unknown
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sm-mta[1654]: q8LDMY0I001654: <noreply@hostname.domain.com>... User unknown
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sendmail[1653]: q8LDMYgp001653: to=noreply@hostname.domain.com, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=31489, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sm-mta[1654]: q8LDMY0I001654: from=<>, size=1489, class=0, nrcpts=0, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sendmail[1653]: q8LDMYgp001653: q8LDMYgq001653: return to sender: User unknown
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sm-mta[1654]: q8LDMY0K001654: from=<>, size=4700, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201209211322.q8LDMYgq001653@hostname.domain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sendmail[1653]: q8LDMYgq001653: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=32513, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (q8LDMY0K001654 Message accepted for delivery)
Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sm-mta[1655]: q8LDMY0K001654: to=root, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=34947, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Sep 21 13:22:40 hostname sm-mta[1651]: q8LDMYxB001649: to=<newuser@fakedomain.com>, delay=00:00:06, xdelay=00:00:06, mailer=esmtp, pri=121023, relay=fakedomain.com. [86.48.74.19], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (Ok)
```

### Not Understood By Me

There are several seeming anomalies I do not understand, such as:

- `stat=User unknown`
- `DSN: User unknown`
- `Sep 21 13:22:34 hostname sm-mta[1654]: q8LDMY0I001654: <noreply@hostname.domain.com>... User unknown`
- I can't understand why Drupal's error says `from
  noreply@hostname.domain.com to noreply@hostname.domain.com`
- I can send mail from the command line using `sendmail`, and it goes through just fine:

### Contents of mail.log after sending with the command line on root

```
Sep 21 16:00:07 hostname sendmail[3283]: q8LFwxIS003283: from=root, size=167, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201209211558.q8LFwxIS003283@hostname.domain.com>, relay=root@localhost
Sep 21 16:00:07 hostname sm-mta[3305]: q8LG07FE003305: from=<root@hostname.domain.com>, size=487, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201209211558.q8LFwxIS003283@hostname.domain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Sep 21 16:00:07 hostname sendmail[3283]: q8LFwxIS003283: to=gmail.account@gmail.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:01:08, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30167, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (q8LG07FE003305 Message accepted for delivery)
Sep 21 16:00:08 hostname sm-mta[3307]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Sep 21 16:00:08 hostname sm-mta[3307]: q8LG07FE003305: to=<gmail.account@gmail.com>, ctladdr=<root@hostname.domain.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=120487, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.142.26], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1348243208 ut4si13805795igb.1)
```

Comment: There are 2 things to check a) IF the mail server is setup properly. b) Check if the email id exist

Comment: I can send mail through the command line using `sendmail` on the root account.  I have updated the post with the mail.log contents when doing that.

Comment: Now we know the mail server works. For my second question does this email id noreply@hostname.domain.com exist ??

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't actually know where to look for or create email ids. (Which means that could be my problem, since all emails except for emails from root@ end up in everyones spam accounts).  Where should I start?

Comment: It depends on what kind of hosting do you use. You should check with your hosting providers. If you are using gmail business accounts then they have an option to add an email id and then you should be ready to go.

Comment: But before you do that I would suggest you trigger it with an email id which already exist and confirm if it is the same issue.

Comment: I've set this Ubuntu distro up myself on my VPS. It's unmanaged.

Comment: Do I have to create the user in my distro in order to email from theusername@my.domain.com ?

Comment: how is your @domain.com email setup. Are you using some third party tools like gmail and are trying to setup mx records on your server ??

Comment: Also do you have an admin interface or login for your VPS server ?? You should have one

Comment: vePortal, but there are no options for email setup.  Surely this is something to handle from within Ubuntu?  If not, then can you give me a short explanation why not?

Comment: Just try and setup a new linux user on the system with the above email id and then try if it works

Comment: I never set up an MX record on my domain.. is this the problem? If so, why is root allowed to send emails?

Comment: MX record is used if you are using a third party email system like gmail and your domain name to route your emails.

Comment: I'm only using what came with the ubuntu distro, aside from the packages I listed above (and a few other things like wget, php-dev, php-pear, etc)

Comment: I am not a linux guru so I would suggest you look at another stack exchange forum called http://askubuntu.com. Also here is a link to one of the questions which I found http://askubuntu.com/questions/54960/how-do-i-set-up-an-email-server

Comment: Thank you, I have seen that, but have already tried postfix, etc.. and seeing that root can send emails just fine, I'd rather not complicate things until the problem is understood.  I have just used "adduser" and created noreply... everything works fine now.  I will bring this issue to askubuntu now to find out why.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error appeared after I've changed my host name from webserver to webserver.com, thus anything sent to `*@webserver.com` confused sendmail, as it's been searching local user with such name.

Adding a local user won't solve the problem completely, because if you try adding user like `firstname.lastname`, Linux system will complain.

What I've done though to fix my system, is **configuring sendmail properly**:

1. Modify `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` by adding following lines to the very end:

   ```
   define('MAIL_HUB', 'webserver.com.');
   define('LOCAL_RELAY', 'webserver.com.');
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   sudo sendmailconfig
   ```

Optionally reloaded the sendmail by:

```
service sendmail restart
```

On some Linux distributions (such as Ubuntu) it may be reloaded automatically.

Comment: I haven't tested this yet, but had finally arrived at the conclusion that this was related to the host name.  This sounds about right, I hadno idea how to set it though, will update after trying this.

Answer (score 1):

I still do not understand why, but creating a linux user on my Ubuntu VPS named "noreply" fixed this issue.  I am happy it works, but would appreciate an answer from anyone who might have insight or an alternative solution other than creating new linux users for every email id I want to send from.

Special thanks to [junedkazi](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/4207/junedkazi) for discussing this with me in comments.

Comment: Also not really sure why this question doesn't deserve credit while some of the others I've seen are practically useless.  Oh well.  :-)

Comment: maybe because this is a sendmail (http://serverfault.com/) question and it doesn't really belong on the drupal site? Anyway sendmail needs a user per account by default to store it's email in ( not sure you can change that ) so that why you needed to create the unix user.